# Is root collection permission extended to sub collections in Firebase?

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

if I have the following rule:

```
match /users/{userId} {
   allow read, write: if request.auth.uid == userId;
}
```

will the user be able to read/write to all the sublcollections as well. If not how would I allow the user permissions to all the sub collections from the root out..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you've currently written the rule, it only applies to the documents in `/users` itself and not to subcollections.

If you want to allow access to the subcollections too, you can change the match to:

```
match /users/{userId=**} {
```

See the Firebase documentation on [securing hierarchical data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-structure#hierarchical_data), specifically the section on [recursive wildcards](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-structure#recursive_wildcards).